# do we need using for the SqlCommand or is it enough just for the SqlConnection and SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

i took this code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

```
string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerId, CompanyName FROM Customers";

      conn.Open();

      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (dr.Read())
          Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
      }
    }
```

as you can see there is no using for the SqlCommand here, so, does it needs to be ?

Comment: I'm thinking that since the connection was used to create the command, than when you dispose it the command will also get disposed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a `using` for every object you create that implements `IDisposable`. That includes the `SqlCommand` and the `SqlConnection`.

---

There are very few exceptions to this rule. The main exception is WCF client proxies. Due to a design flaw, their `Dispose` method can sometimes throw an exception. If you used the proxy in a `using` statement, this second exception would cause you to lose the original exception.

Comment: +1, but to be perfectly clear on the WCF issue: it doesn't mean that you should just ignore that the client is disposable. Rather, it means that you should wrap the call in a try/finally block and wrap the Close/Dispose operation inside the finally block in a try/catch block. Very ugly, though...

Comment: @MarkSeemann I have found that using overloaded methods helps to clean up such try...finally mess a lot. That's a personal opinion, of course.

Comment: I disagree with the terms "need" and "rule" unqualified .. it is a "rule" when adhering to our best practice "policy".  Still, this question raises a consideration with SqlCommand (DbCommand), which is constructed/initialized with SqlConnection (DbConnection). Is `DbConnection` being disposed of when DbCommand.Dispose() is called on?

Comment: @brett: Unqualified statements are better, in general. Perhaps 20% of .NET developers should consider violating this rule. I mean 20% of the most experienced. To the rest, it should be "need" and "rule".

Comment: @brett, as to DbConnection, take a look at the code and see. But it would be a bad idea to depend on undocumented functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You don't **NEED** to use a using statement, but it is good practice and you **SHOULD** use it.  It allows objects using IDisposable to be disposed of automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx

**Edited to add link and remove inaccurate statement because @John Saunders is right.**

Comment: `IDisposable` isn't about memory usage. It's about _resource_ usage.

Comment: I thought that since the connection was used to create the command, than when you dispose it the command will also get disposed

Comment: but presumably the SqlCommand isn't holding any resources open, since the Connection that created the SqlCommand has been closed...

Comment: @Omu: No, not documented as such, so assume it's not true.

Comment: @rohancragg: I wouldn't make assumptions about something like that. Even if it were true in the current release, it may not be true in some future release.

Comment: fair enough, I agree anyway, I'd personally put the using in wherever possible