# .NET IDisposable use responsibilities, example SqlCommand

Tags: .net, idisposable

The MSDN documentation says that "If your app simply uses an object that **implements IDisposable**, don't provide an IDisposable implementation. Instead, you should call the object's IDisposable.Dispose implementation when you are finished using it."

**How far up the inheritance hiearachy are you obligate to look?**  For example, the SqlCommand does not implement IDisposable; however, its parent class DBCommand does.  And the MSDN doc example on SqlCommand does not include a Using Clause.

Also, from the MSDN docs ([IDisposable and the inheritance hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)), if you derive from a base that implements IDisposable, you are obligated to override Disposable. Which SqlCommand obviously does (cf referencesource.microsoft.com).  But it also includes "Note that derived classes **do not themselves implement** the IDisposable interface and do not include a parameterless Dispose method. ".

So does SqlCommand "implement IDisposable" as defined in the first quoted doc at top, or as in the second quoted just above?

For almost a decade no one has changed the example at MSDN.

At any rate, this is just an example.  Again, my question is how far up the inheritance tree is one obligated to look to find out whether something implements IDisposable?

(note: 
The specific question about SqlCommand is asked here ([do we need using for the SqlCommand or is it enough just for the SqlConnection and SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252062/do-we-need-using-for-the-sqlcommand-or-is-it-enough-just-for-the-sqlconnection-a)), but as far as i can tell, my generic question hasn't been asked)

Answer (score 2):

If a parent type (DbCommand) implements IDisposable, then its inherited types (SqlCommand) will need to be disposed.

You may be misinterpreting the MSDN docs:

> "If your app simply uses an object that implements IDisposable, don't
>   provide an IDisposable implementation. Instead, you should call the
>   object's IDisposable.Dispose implementation when you are finished
>   using it."

This refers not to inheritance, but to using an IDisposable you acquired from somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I am specifically referring to use of a class derived from an IDisposable.   I think its probably just crappy MSDN documentation.  None of their examples of other DbCommand-derived classes includes "using" around the derived instance.  The more i think about it, it needs to be used.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using a class like SqlCommand that derives from a base class which implements IDisposable, yeah, you'll still need to dispose.

Comment: @user2457760 If this doesn't answer your question, feel free to clarify. To me, your question reads as one about whether to dispose objects that inherit from base types that implement IDisposable. The answer is yes, you still need to dispose those derived types.